How to solve storage error when all accounts in my organization have no storage using at all
I have cloud identity free subscription and I have about five users. I got this error now.

And it is showing like this.
But all my users don't have any data in google drive.

So, I have no idea how to solve this. May I know how I can solve this? Thank you.
I would like to solve my issue.
